# Resulting Jar From Ant Builder Can't be Seen in Eclipse Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build-process

I have a java project in Eclipse that is built through ANT.   Normally, I see the resulting Jar appear in the workspace in Eclipse.  Suddenly, for this project only, the jar just doesn't show up within Eclipse.  I know the jar is being created because when I look at the workspace within Windows Explorer, I see the Jar.    How can I get Eclipse to show the resulting jar from a build within Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a problem of refreshing your workspace or your project directories.

However, you can do that automatically: In this project properties, select `Builders`, then `Ant Builder`. In the properties of this builder, go in `Refresh` tab, and check the `Resfresh resources upon completion` and choose `The project containing the selected resource` option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried refreshing your workspace?  Right-click->Refresh, or just press F5.